# Прижать футер к нижней части экрана

Tags: html, html5, css

Возникла такая проблема: пытаюсь прижать футер к нижней части экрана, с помощью таких свойств:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  min-width: 480px;
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
* html #wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#middle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 100px;
  height: 1%;
  position: relative;
}
#middle:after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
  padding: 0 270px 0 0;
}

/* Sidebar Right
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#sideRight {
  float: left;
  margin-right: -3px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  position: relative;
}
/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #010101;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -120px;
  left: 0;
}

<div id="wrapper">
<header id="header">
Тут вложено куча дивов
</header>
</div><!--#WRAPPER-->
<section id="middle">
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
Тут вложено куча дивов
</div><!-- #content-->
</div><!-- #container-->
<aside id="sideRight">
</aside><!-- #sideRight -->
</section><!-- #middle-->
<footer id="footer">
</footer>
```

Есть страницы где все ок, но а есть где футер наезжает на контент, в IE вообще беда((
Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать верстку кросс-браузерной. Буду очень благодарен любой помощи, так как нет профессиональных навыков верстки...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вникал в код, но примерно так

```
#footer{    
    position:fixed;    
    bottom:0;    
    left:0;    
    width: 100%;    
    height: 150px;    
    background-color: #010101;    
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую. При выставлении position: fixed; для footer стало еще хуже чем со значением position: absolute; И IE, даже версии 8, не хочет работать, контент залазит под футер.

Comment: Мне кажется, что тогда уже лучше прописать position: relative; для футера, но тогда на страницах где мало контента он не прижимается к нижней части экрана, хотя плюс в том, что в Опере и ИЕ глюков никаких нет.