# Как прижать footer к низу экрана?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть основной блок `<div class="container"></div>` с контентом различной высоты, а под ним размещён футер.

Если контент не достигает всей высоты экрана, нужно чтобы блок `.container` занимал всё свободное место окна браузера. При этом футер должен быть внизу страницы и оставаться видимым.

Футер может менять высоту, но при этом он должен оставаться прижатым к нижнему краю окна браузера.

```css
.container {
   background: #fff;
   margin: auto;
   height: auto;
   width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main class="container">
   content
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Пробовали использовать media queries?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подвал не фиксированной высоты прижатый к низу экрана](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/185665/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: Это дубликат [вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/108495/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/109268), а не наоборот.

Comment: я так понимаю, что у Вас должен контент постоянно меняться, в зависимости от выбранных вкладок в каком-то меню. Я тоже сталкивался с моментами, когда нужно было, чтоб футер четко был внизу при , практически пустом контенте (даже немного скролил). Я такой момент решал бонально просто: в своем файле css  я ставил .content { min-height: 600px; } ( ну или 500-700px  в зависимости от того какой высоты у Вас хедер, просто просчитываете контент). Я не говорю, что это решение оригинальное, но в своих проектах я его использовал и мне это не доставляло неудобств в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

***Для прижатия футера к низу экрана, есть несколько решений. Ниже представлены варианты от самого актуального до устаревшего:***

#### 1. Решение через Grid Layout для АДАПТИВНОЙ высоты футера

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

header {
  background: blue;
}

main {
  background: red;
}

footer {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  header
</header>
<main role="main">
  content
</main>
<footer role="contentinfo">
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 2. Решение через Flexbox для АДАПТИВНОЙ высоты футера

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
   background: blue;
}

main {
  /* Чтобы занимал оставшееся пространство */
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: red;
}

footer {
  /* Чтобы footer не уменьшался */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  header
</header>
<main role="main">
  content
</main>
<footer role="contentinfo">
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 3. Решение через таблицы для АДАПТИВНОЙ высоты футера

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: table;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

header {
   background: blue;
}

main {
  display: table-row;
  /* Чтобы ряд занимал всё оставшееся пространство, так как табличная разметка не позволит ему вытолкнуть header и footer */
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

footer {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  header
</header>
<main role="main">
  content
</main>
<footer role="contentinfo">
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 4. Решение на нативном JavaScript для АДАПТИВНОЙ высоты футера

```js
// Высчитываем высоту footer и делаем соответствующий отступ от main:
function footer() {
    const
        main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0],
        footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0]

    main.style.paddingBottom = footer.clientHeight + 'px'
}

window.addEventListener('load', footer);
window.addEventListener('resize', footer);
```

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
   background: blue;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer по умолчанию */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background: red;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer по умолчанию */
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  header
</header>
<main role="main">
  content
</main>
<footer role="contentinfo">
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 5. Решение через calc() для ФИКСИРОВАННОЙ высоты футера

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
   background: blue;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer и header */
  min-height: calc(100vh - 30px - 18px);
  background: red;
}

footer {
  /* Высота footer */
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  header
</header>
<main role="main">
  content
</main>
<footer role="contentinfo">
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 6. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование для ФИКСИРОВАННОЙ высоты футера

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
   background: blue;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background: red;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer */
  height: 30px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  header
</header>
<main role="main">
  content
</main>
<footer role="contentinfo">
  footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Если надо чтобы решение на Flexbox работало в IE, то я у себя в ответе в секции Internet Explorer есть решение.

Comment: Также приведенное решение на CSS Grid Layout негибкое (требует фиксированной высоты) и не работает в IE 10/11, что исправлено в моём ответе.

Answer (score 22):

## Решение на `flexbox`.

Более универсальное в плане сопровождаемости, так как не требует задания фиксированной высоты и хаков с `position: absolute`. Если вам требуется также поддерживать IE 10/11, то решение включающее их поддержку находится в секции "Flexbox для Internet Explorer 10/11".

Случай с контентом на всю оставшуюся высоту:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  /* Занять всё оставшееся пространство */
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Если надо чтобы был отступ от контента, но контент не занимал всю высоту, то используйте `margin-top: auto` для `footer`:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

footer {
  /* Опустить в самый низ */
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

### Flexbox для Internet Explorer 10/11

Для того, чтобы описанные выше способы заработали в IE 10/11 нужно помнить о следующих багах браузеров:

- `min-height` не применяется к элементу с `display: flex` и `flex-direction: column` в IE 10-11. Используйте `height` где это возможно.
- Chrome, Opera, and Safari не учитывают минимальный размер контента непосредственных детей контейнера c `display: flex`. Установите `flex-shrink` в `0` (вместо значения по умолчанию `1`) чтобы избежать нежелательного "сжатия".

Случай с контентом на всю оставшуюся высоту:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
  /* Занять всё оставшееся пространство */
  flex-grow: 1;
  
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Если надо чтобы был отступ от контента:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header,
footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.content {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

footer {
  /* Опустить в самый низ */
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

## CSS Grid Layout

Случай с контентом на всю оставшуюся высоту:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  
  display: grid;
  
  /* задаём высоту строк */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.content {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Если надо чтобы был отступ от контента, но контент не занимал всю высоту, то используйте `align-self: start` для `footer`:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  display: grid;

  /* задаём высоту строк */
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.content {
  /* кладём элемент в начало ячейки по вертикали */
  /* чтобы его высота была равна высоте контента */
  align-self: start;
  
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

### CSS Grid Layout для Internet Explorer 10/11

В Internet Explorer 10/11 реализована устаревшая версия модуля CSS Grid Layout. С практической точки зрения это значит, что реализация этого модуля очень сильно разнится от остальных браузеров, которые поддерживают данный модуль.

Самое главное, о чём нужно помнить, что в IE элементы не располагаются по умолчанию по свободным ячейкам по порядку, а просто кладутся друг на друга в самую первую ячейку. То есть в других браузерах значения по умолчанию `grid-row : auto` и `grid-column: auto`, тогда как в IE `-ms-grid-row : 1` и `-ms-column: 1`, поэтому если номер строки или стоблца элемента не совпадают с `1`, то придётся их прописывать по другому.

Оставльное — более тривиально. Часть свойств не поддерживаются (вроде `grid-areas`, `grid-gap` и т.д.), часть называются по другому или требуется другой синтаксис и могут иметь отличные умолчания.

Случай с контентом на всю оставшуюся высоту:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;

  /* по умолчанию в IE размер ячеек равен содержимому, */
  /* тогда как в других браузерах размер ячеек растягивается */
  /* под свобоодное пространство grid-контейера */
  -ms-grid-columns: 100%;

  /* задаём высоту строк */
  -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.content {
  /* явно прописываем номер строки, когда она не равна 1 */
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  
  border: 1px dotted red;  
}

footer {
  /* явно прописываем номер строки, когда она не равна 1 */
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Если надо чтобы был отступ от контента, но контент не занимал всю высоту, то используйте `align-self: start` и `-ms-grid-row-align: start` для `footer`:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;

  /* по умолчанию в IE размер ячеек равен содержимому, */
  /* тогда как в других браузерах размер ячеек растягивается */
  /* под свобоодное пространство grid-контейера */
  -ms-grid-columns: 100%;

  /* задаём высоту строк, разные имена свойств */
  -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.content {
  /* явно прописываем номер строки, когда она не равна 1 */
  -ms-grid-row: 2;
  
  /* кладём элемент в начало ячейки по вертикали */
  /* чтобы его высота была равна высоте контента */
  -ms-grid-row-align: start;
  align-self: start;
  
  border: 1px dotted red;  
}

footer {
  /* явно прописываем номер строки, когда она не равна 1 */
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
}

.content {
  -ms-grid-row: 2;

  
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

footer {
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content
</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 7):

Можно ещё так, с проверкой (если мало контента, то фиксировать, иначе статика):

```js
if( $(document).height() <= $(window).height() ){  
  $(".page-footer").addClass("fixed-bottom");
}
```

```css
.page-footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-footer.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, harum. Sapiente dignissimos in provident fugit voluptatem commodi, ipsa blanditiis assumenda quasi amet excepturi nostrum voluptatum molestiae ratione, corrupti hic voluptatibus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum accusamus cum voluptas voluptate esse asperiores cupiditate velit quaerat optio, praesentium ipsa, deserunt veniam facilis libero accusantium! Similique accusamus assumenda beatae amet harum delectus quisquam minima quidem id veniam a eaque iste labore distinctio quia cupiditate, ullam suscipit. Repellendus, porro, officiis!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero atque officia, hic iure placeat, dolores amet eaque quae, eveniet laboriosam voluptatibus fugit velit aut. Facilis expedita, id quasi asperiores molestiae, numquam provident consectetur maxime ad dolorem illo, voluptas dolore accusantium quam deleniti enim ratione doloremque cum omnis ea maiores, deserunt earum eveniet minima eaque. Soluta earum amet esse rem vitae eaque enim aut obcaecati laudantium provident eius delectus nulla doloremque omnis quisquam, ut eos modi, autem tenetur! Deserunt pariatur cum aspernatur aperiam, obcaecati libero, tenetur veritatis aut praesentium architecto optio perspiciatis quo ut. Atque, soluta doloribus recusandae quibusdam ipsam qui!
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, unde.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus perspiciatis molestiae nemo soluta nesciunt alias porro impedit, perferendis molestias possimus mollitia asperiores laboriosam consectetur enim odit, animi facere earum consequatur in veniam neque quae esse. Beatae iure laboriosam optio? Pariatur.
  </p>
</main>
  
  <footer class="page-footer">
    FOOTER
  </footer>
```

мало контента:

```js
if( $(document).height() <= $(window).height() ){  
  $(".page-footer").addClass("fixed-bottom");
}
```

```css
.page-footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-footer.fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
<main>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, harum. Sapiente dignissimos in provident fugit voluptatem commodi, ipsa blanditiis assumenda quasi amet excepturi nostrum voluptatum molestiae ratione, corrupti hic voluptatibus.
  </p>
</main>
  
  <footer class="page-footer">
    FOOTER
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 6):

Раз 5 прочитал вопрос и не уверен, что понял, чего хочет автор, но все же.
Если хочешь, чтобы на разных экранах элементы `div` вели себя по разному, то можно задать в `css`:

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container { 
    /* задавай свойства какие тебе надо */
  }

  .можно_дописать_еще_класс_других_div_или_чего_тебе_хочется {
   }
 }
```

А если тебе надо, чтобы блоки вели себя корректно на разных экранах и не надо было мотать страничку влево и вправо, то вот почитай http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/. Все очень просто.

Answer (score 3):

Пожалуй самое компактное решение на css через **calc()** с добавлением всего пары свойств min-height и height

```css
main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}

footer {
  height: 50px; background: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <header>header</header>
    content
  </main>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

**7. Решение через Grid Layout для ЛЮБОЙ высоты футера**

Это вариант значительно полезнее, чем №6, так как и хедер и футер могут быть **любой высоты** - под их контент и **кода заметно меньше** - нужно всего 2 строчки.
Применяйте, если пишете используя Grid Layout.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
  background: blue;
}

main {
  background: red;
}

footer {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner">
  header<br>header
</header>
<main role="main">
  content
</main>
<footer role="contentinfo">
  footer<br>footer<br>footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Футер состоящий из нескольких блоков, думаю этот кусочек кода подойдёт.

Answer (score 2):

Вставляешь в то место, где тебе надо раздуть свою страницу `<div class="empty-space-filler"></div>`, а потом с помощью jQuery делаешь так:

```
let counter = 1;
while ($('body').height() < window.innerHeight){
    $('.empty-space-filler').css('height', counter);
    counter++;
}
```

Также можешь своему .container менять свойство max-height

Answer (score -3):

Примените
`min-height: 95%;` для .container, а `height: 5%;` - для .footer

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?