# Как прижать footer к низу страницы

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">    <!--  Контейнер сайта  -->
<div id="header">      <!--    Шапка  -->
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="main-navigation">

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Стpаница 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Стpаница 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Стpаница 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Стpаница 4</a>
                </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
 <div class="wrapper">  <!-- /-- Основной контент левой колонки--/ -->
        <div class="logo">  <!-- /-- Логотип --/ -->
            <a href="#"> 
                <img src="images/logo.png">
            </a> 
        </div>
<nav class="bottom_menu">   <!-- /-- Начало навигации --/ -->
            <ul id="dropdown_nav">
                <li><a href="#">Категория</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Подменю #1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подменю #2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подменю #3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Подменю #4</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <li><a href="#">Категория 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Категория 4</a></li>
                </li>
            </ul>
</nav>                      <!-- /-- Конец навигации --/ -->
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Последние записи</h2>
        </div>

    <div class="middle"></div>      <!-- /-- Пустое место --/ -->

    <div class="postbox">           <!-- /-- Левая информационная колонка --/ -->
        <a href="#">
            <img src="images/tumb.png">
        </a>
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Скачать бесплатно 15 HTML5 и CSS3 шаблонов</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="info">
        Александр //<a href="#">Метки: метка, метка 2</a>// Апр.10.2012. // Комментариев:<a href="#">238</a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
        <p>Приветствую Вас, уважаемые читатели блога. Сегодня спешу представить Вам очередную бесплатную подборку шаблонов на CSS3 и HTML5, а также здесь есть несколько шаблонов с большими и встроенными JQuery слайдерами изображений. В общем, я надеюсь, что Вы здесь найдёте то что Вам нужно. Наслаждайтесь.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-next"><a href="#">Далее</a></div>
    </div>  
    <div class="raz"></div>
</div>
  <aside id="colRight">         <!-- /-- Правая панель ссылок --/ -->
        <form  method="get" action="/search" target="_blank">
        <input name="q" id="form-query" value="" placeholder="Поиск..."> 
        <input id="form-querysub" type=submit value="">
        </form>
        <div class="rightBox">
            <h3>Виджет 1</h3>       
            <ul>    
                <li>
                    <a href="#" title="Плавная анимация объектов только с помощью CSS (5 примеров)">Плавная анимация объектов только с помощью CSS (5 примеров)</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Скачать бесплатно 15 HTML5 и CSS3 шаблонов для Ваших новых идей и веб &#8211; проектов</a>
                </li>
        <li>
                    <a href="#">Скачать бесплатно 15 HTML5 и CSS3 шаблонов для Ваших новых идей и веб &#8211; проектов</a>
                </li>
        <li>
                    <a href="#">Скачать бесплатно 15 HTML5 и CSS3 шаблонов для Ваших новых идей и веб &#8211; проектов</a>
                </li>
    </ul>  
    </div>
      </aside>   
  <footer id="footer">  
    <div class="footerInner">
        <div class="mini-logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <nav class="main-navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Станица 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Станица 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Станица 3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Станица 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>  
</footer>
</body>
</html>



html {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color:#333;
    background: #fff; 
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:0.94em;
    line-height:135%;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

#container{
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    height: 100%;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
    height:57px;
    background:#0dbfe5;

}
.container{
    margin-left:40px;
    min-height:100%;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;


}
a:hover{
    text-align:center;
    background: #fff;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
}

#main-navigation, #main-navigation li{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;


}

#main-navigation{
    background:#0dbfe5;

}

#main-navigation ul{
    overflow:hidden;

}
#main-navigation li{
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
#main-navigation a{
    border-left:1px solid #adadad;
    display:block;
    color:#d7d4d4;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:19px 20px 18px 20px;
}

.net-block{

}

.wrapper{
    width:1200px;
    margin-right:40px;
    min-height:100%;
}

.logo{
    width:141px;
    height:47px;
    margin-top:33px;
    margin-bottom:42px;
    margin-left:40px;
}

.bottom_menu{
    margin-left:40px;
    width:1200px;
    height:70px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#dropdown_nav, #dropdown_nav li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:0px solid #777;
    margin-top:18px;

}

#dropdown_nav{
    background:#323232;
    width:1200px;
}
#dropdown_nav li{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;       
}

#dropdown_nav a{
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 22px 20px 22px;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:18px;
    /*background: url(images/linemenu.png) right no-repeat;*/
}

#dropdown_nav li a:hover {
    background: #000;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#0dbfe5;
}

#dropdown_nav li:hover>.sub-menu{
    display:block;
}

#dropdown_nav .sub-menu{
    z-index: 4;
    width:150px;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:42px;
    left:0px;
    border:0px solid #ddd;
    border-top:none;
    background: #000;
    display:none;

}

#dropdown_nav .sub-menu li{            
    width:150px;
    padding:0px;

}

#dropdown_nav .sub-menu li a {
    background: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:15px;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:0px solid #e5e0b3;
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#fff; 

}

#dropdown_nav .sub-menu li a:hover {
    background:#222;
    color:#0dbfe5;
    text-align:left;
}

.content{
    width:1200px;
    height:103px;
    background:#eeeeee;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    text-align:center;
}           

h2{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:40px;
}

.middle{
    width:1200px;
    height:46px;
    background:#fff;
    border:0px solid #e5e0b3;
    margin-left:40px;
}

.postbox{
    border:0px solid #333;
    background: #fff;
    width:700px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    float:left;
}

.postbox h3 a{
    font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight", "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color:#000;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:33px;
}

.postbox h3 a:hover{
    color:#0dbfe5;
}

.postbox info{
    margin-bottom:17px;
    margin-top:20px;
    color:#999;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:14px;
}

.postbox info a{
    color:#777;
}

.postbox info a:hover{
    color:#4991bb;
}

.postbox text{
    border:0px solid #333;
    width:700px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

.postbox text p{
    margin-top:0;
}

.bottom-next a{
     background:#0dbfe5;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 17px; 
     width: 100px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     text-align:center;
     padding:6px 25px 9px 25px;
}

.bottom-next a:hover{
    background:#000;
    color:#0dbfe5;
}

.raz{
    margin:0 auto;
    border:0px solid #333;
    background: #fff;
    width:116px;
    height:29px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#colRight{
    float:right;
    width:350px;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:70px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

#form-query {

    background:#eeeeee;
    border:0px solid #e4e4e4;
    width:350px;
    height:31px;
    padding:8px 10px 7px;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top:0px;

}

#form-querysub {
    position:absolute;
    right:7px;
    top:7px;
    width:17px;
    height:17px;
    background:#d7d7d7;
    border:0px dashed #333;
}

#form-querysub:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.rightBox h3{
    background:#d7d7d7;
    border:1px solid #e1e3e3;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.rightBox{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;


}

.rightBox li{
    background:#fff;
    border-top:1px solid #e1e3e3;
    padding:10px 0px;



}

.rightBox ul{
    background:#fff;
    border-top:0px solid #e1e3e3;
    padding:10px 0px;
}

.rightBox li:first-child {
    border-top:none;
}

.rightBox a {
    color:#333;
}

.rightBox a:hover {
    color:#0dbfe5;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;

}

#footer {
    margin-top:50px;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background: #0dbfe5;
}

.footerInner {
    position:relative;
    border:0px solid #000;
    width:1200px;
    margin:-50px;
    height:100px;
}
```

`Footer` находится посередине страницы и никуда не двигается.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прижимать footer всегда к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать так, чтобы подвал (footer) был всегда внизу окна браузера при том, что на странице недостаточно контента, то можете использовать такой код:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
}
main {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  /*Высота футера*/
}
footer {
  margin-top: -100px;
  /*Минус Высота футера*/
  height: 100px;
  /*Высота футера*/
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <header>
    <p>Содержимое заголовка</p>
  </header>

  <main>
    <p>Основное содержимое</p>
  </main>
</div>

<footer>
  <p>Содержимое подвала</p>
</footer>
```

Такая разметка предполагает, что все содержимое страницы хранится внутри блока div с id = wrap, а все содержимое футера в блоке footer. Блок header здесь необязателен (предполагается, что в нем хранится шапка страницы, например, меню). Блок main обязателен.

Также вы можете заменить footer, main, #wrap на блоки div или другие элементы, но потребуется поправить стиль.

Если вас устраивает main, #wrap, footerr, имейте в виду, что в браузере IE < 9 потребуется подключить скрипт html5shiv, поскольку старые IE не понимают теги html5

Answer (score 13):

Можно прижать с помощью флексбокс, тогда высота футера может быть разной, а верстка соответственно адаптивной:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;/*это свойство можно удалить, если вы используете reset, normalize или нечто подобное*/
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  
  padding: 1rem;/*это свойство можно удалить, добавлено для наглядности*/
  background: #e6f2ff;/*это свойство можно удалить, добавлено для наглядности*/
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  
  padding: 1rem;/*это свойство можно удалить, добавлено для наглядности*/
  background: #e6ffe6;/*это свойство можно удалить, добавлено для наглядности*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал сделать это различными способами.
В случае, если контента немного, футер действительно можно зафиксировать в нижней части страницы.
Но когда контекст не помещается на странице, футер все равно "выдавливается" за нижний край страницы.
Решил это следующим образом:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Тестовая страница</title>
<link href="Test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="header">
         </div>
         <div class="content">
            <p>
                  Здесь нужно разместить длинный текст
            </p>
        </div>
         <div class="footer">  
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
  margin: 0; /*Сбрасываем настройки браузера*/
}

.wrap {
  position:fixed; /*Отсоединяем контейнер от страницы и фиксируем в окне браузера*/
  width: 100%;   /*Ширина на все окно браузера*/
  height: 100%;  /*Высота на все окно браузера*/
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex; /*Превращаем контейнер в flexBox*/
  flex-direction: column; /*Расставляем дочерние элементы по вертикали*/
}

.header{
  height: 32px;
  background-color: burlywood;  
  flex-grow: 0; /*Запрещаем увеличиваться*/
  flex-shrink: 0; /*Запрещаем сжиматься*/
  flex-basis: auto;  
}

  .content {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    overflow-y:auto; /*Вертикальная полоса прокрутки для текста*/
    padding: 10px; /*отступы текста со всех сторон*/
    text-align: justify; /*выравнивание текста по левому и правому краям*/     
    flex-grow: 1; /*Предписываем занять все свободное пространство*/
}

.footer {
  height: 32px;
  background-color: cadetblue;  
  flex-grow: 0; /*Запрещаем увеличиваться*/
  flex-shrink: 0; /*Запрещаем сжиматься*/
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```