# Как правильно позиционировать footer на сайте?

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

На сайте есть header, content и footer блоки.
У content на разных страницах разная высота, бывает что высота меньше чем body и тогда шапка находится не внизу страницы а выше. Как правильно позиционировать футер? Нужно ли устанавливать минимальную высоту для content чтобы прижать footer  к низу? Хотя минимальную высоту я установить не могу, так как высота на разных устройствах разная. Как поступать в таких случаях?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

футер прижимается вниз путём его абсолютного позиционирования и вытягивания высоты родительских блоков: html, body и блока с классом .wrapper на 100%. При этом конкретному блоку .content необходимо задать нижний отступ, который равен или больше высоты футера, в противном случае последний закроет часть содержимого.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Text footer</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Как-то так

Comment: я иногда использую вот этот метод, но он работает только в современных браузерах
`* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
}` но тут надо знать конретную высоту футера

Comment: Спасибо, видимо первый способ предпочтителен, раз работает в большем количестве браузеров. position: relative; для wrapper зачем нужен? А так же меня интересует почему именно absolute использовано для футера? Понятно что это нужно чтобы сделать отсчет от нижнего края род. блока, но при этом другие элементы отображаются на веб-странице словно абсолютно позиционированного элемента и нет. Это не мешает? Это значит что блок как бы идет поверх контента и остальные элементы были бы под ним, если бы не padding у контента?

Answer (score 6):

Пользуюсь таким методом:

```
<html class="with-sticky-footer">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="body-before-footer">
      <!-- Ваш основной контент -->
    </div>
    <footer>
      <!-- Контент футера -->
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Класс `with-sticky-footer` - чтобы не перегружать стандартные стили `html` и `body`, так как футер может встречаться не на всех страницах сайта.

Стили:

```
html.with-sticky-footer {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
html.with-sticky-footer body {
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  position: initial;
}
html.with-sticky-footer .body-before-footer {
  background: #fff;
}
html.with-sticky-footer footer {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Цвет `background: #fff;` у `.body-before-footer` задается такой же, как у `body`. Это помогает, если вы хотите расположить футер фиксированно и как бы "под" контентом. Посмотрите, как это реализовано здесь: http://rubycourses.ru/. Я просто задал цвет для `.body-before-footer` и `position: fixed` для футера.

Comment: По поводу вашего примера: Зачем у html position: relative, у body position: initial? И собственно у футера absolute? На сколько я знаю при абсолютном позиционировании все HTML элементы ведут себя так, будто абсолютно позиционированного элемента в потоке нет. То есть футер будет как бы отдельно от всех элементов, возможно поверх них. Так же не ясно зачем футеру min-width: 100%;

Answer (score 6):

То что вы хотите сделать, называется **Sticky Footer** (липкий футер). Существует множество способов реализовать подобное поведение.

##1. Отрицательный margin у footer-а

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content-inside {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-inside">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

##2. Отрицательный margin у content

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.footer,
.push {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    content
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

##3. С помощью calc()

```css
.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

##4. Через свойство flexbox

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

##5. Через свойство grid

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}

.footer {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Какой из этих способов используете вы? Какой более универсальный для большинства браузеров?

Comment: Наиболее современный и простой способ это 4. flexbox . Но, как и все новое, его не поддерживают старые браузеры https://webref.ru/css/flex . В проектах не требующих широкой поддержки браузеров, я использую его. Наиболее универсальные и кросбраузерные методы 1 и 2, через отрицательные margin-ы.