# Слайдер прилип к footer

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

`Footer` находится поверх слайдера, точнее точки слайдера сдвигаются вместе с `Footer'ом`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**СSS**:

```
#forfooter {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;

}
```

**HTML**:

```
<body>
    <!-- Общий div для всей в -->
    <div class="maindiv" id="main_div">
        <!-- Блок хедера (шапка сайта) -->
        <div id="forheader">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/900x108" width="900" height="108" alt="Хедер" title="Шапка сайта" />
        </div>
        <!-- Конец блока хедера -->
        <div id="forbody">
            <div class="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills centered" id='MenuMenu'> <!--Вместо табс можно pills, другие кнопки будут-->
                    <li><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>     
        <!--СЛАЙДЕР -->
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!--Индикаторы слайдов-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li> <!—внизу 3 круглишка-->
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--Слайды-->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание 2 слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание 3 слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Стрелки переключения слайдов-->
    <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
    </a>    
    <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

        <!-- Блок футера -->
        <div id="forfooter">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/900x67" width="900" height="67" alt="Футер" title="Производители" />
        </div>
        <!-- Конец футера -->
    </div>
    <script src="js/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js "></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Задайте для body `margin-bottom: 80px;`. Как правильно делать sticky-футер, читайте здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562100/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-footer-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5

Answer (score 1):

У Вас `footer` внутри карусели.

Либо вынесите ее:

```css
#forfooter {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Общий div для всей в -->
    <div class="maindiv" id="main_div">
        <!-- Блок хедера (шапка сайта) -->
        <div id="forheader">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/900x108" width="900" height="108" alt="Хедер" title="Шапка сайта" />
        </div>
        <!-- Конец блока хедера -->
        <div id="forbody">
            <div class="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills centered" id='MenuMenu'> <!--Вместо табс можно pills, другие кнопки будут-->
                    <li><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>     
        <!--СЛАЙДЕР -->
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!--Индикаторы слайдов-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li> <!—внизу 3 круглишка-->
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--Слайды-->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание 2 слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание 3 слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Стрелки переключения слайдов-->
    <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
    </a>    
    <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

        
    </div>
      
      <!-- Блок футера -->
        <div id="forfooter">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/900x67" width="900" height="67" alt="Футер" title="Производители" />
        </div>
        <!-- Конец футера -->
    <script src="js/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Либо измените положение, задав `bottom: -80px;`:

```css
#forfooter {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: -80px;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Общий div для всей в -->
    <div class="maindiv" id="main_div">
        <!-- Блок хедера (шапка сайта) -->
        <div id="forheader">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/900x108" width="900" height="108" alt="Хедер" title="Шапка сайта" />
        </div>
        <!-- Конец блока хедера -->
        <div id="forbody">
            <div class="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills centered" id='MenuMenu'> <!--Вместо табс можно pills, другие кнопки будут-->
                    <li><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка меню 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>     
        <!--СЛАЙДЕР -->
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!--Индикаторы слайдов-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li> <!—внизу 3 круглишка-->
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--Слайды-->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Первый слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание первого слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Второй слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание 2 слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/948x265" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Третий слайд</h3>
                <p>Описание 3 слайда</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Стрелки переключения слайдов-->
    <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
    </a>    
    <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

        <!-- Блок футера -->
        <div id="forfooter">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/900x67" width="900" height="67" alt="Футер" title="Производители" />
        </div>
        <!-- Конец футера -->
    </div>
    <script src="js/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js "></script>
</body>
</html>
```