# Почему footer не прижимается к низу при использовании float: left?

Tags: css, вёрстка

https://jsfiddle.net/veetwmx0/

**HTML**:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="content" style="text-align:left">

    <div style="padding: 70px; border: 1px solid;">
        <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    </div>


    <div class="content_left" style="float:left; width:50%; border: 1px solid; height: 500px;padding:30px; box-sizing: border-box;">
        <h1>Заголовок 2</h1>
        <p style="margin-top:20px;">

    </div>

    <div class="content_right" style="float:left; width:50%; border: 1px solid;height: 500px; padding:30px; box-sizing: border-box;">
        <h1 style="text-align:left; padding: 0;">Заголовок 3</h1>

    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="footer">
        <ul class="ul_header">
            <li><a href="index.html">Бла</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Бла бла</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**:

```
html,
body{
 background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:#8a98a5
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.ul_header{
margin:0;
padding-left: 300px;
float: left;
}

.ul_header li{
display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
padding: 0 10px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ul_header_right{
  margin:0;
  float: right;
}

.ul_header_right li{
display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
padding: 0 15px;
}

.ul_header_right div{
  float:right;
}

.content{
  width: 1085px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

#footer{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #f4f6f9;
border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
width: 100%;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
}


* {color:#a1afbd}

  p{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.pa {margin-top: 15px !important;}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Почему footer не прижимается к низу при использовании float: left?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `footer` с `position: absolute` позиционируется относительно родителя с `position: relative`. Ближайший это `.wrapper`.

И т.к. для `.content` не задан `overflow: hidden;` или `clearfix`, то плавающие блоки внутри него выпадают. Высота `wrapper` получается меньше ожидаемой.

Просто добавьте **clearfix** плавающим блокам:

```
.content:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```css
html,
body{
 background-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color:#8a98a5
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.content:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ul_header{
margin:0;
padding-left: 300px;
float: left;
}

.ul_header li{
display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
padding: 0 10px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ul_header_right{
  margin:0;
  float: right;
}

.ul_header_right li{
display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
padding: 0 15px;
}

.ul_header_right div{
  float:right;
}

.content{
  width: 1085px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

#footer{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #f4f6f9;
border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
width: 100%;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
}


* {color:#a1afbd}

  p{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.pa {margin-top: 15px !important;}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="content" style="text-align:left">

<div style="padding: 70px; border: 1px solid;">
 <h1>Заголовок</h1>
</div>


<div class="content_left" style="float:left; width:50%; border: 1px solid; height: 500px;padding:30px; box-sizing: border-box;">
 <h1>Заголовок 2</h1>
 <p style="margin-top:20px;">
 
</div>

<div class="content_right" style="float:left; width:50%; border: 1px solid;height: 500px; padding:30px; box-sizing: border-box;">
 <h1 style="text-align:left; padding: 0;">Заголовок 3</h1>
  
</div>
</div>


<div id="footer">
 <ul class="ul_header">
  <li><a href="index.html">Бла</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Бла бла</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

То же касается и если Вы хотите поставить `footer { float: left; }` , а не абсолютное позиционирование.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В чем разница между overflow: hidden; или clearfix? overflow: hidden; работает, зачем писать clearfix который значительно больше?

Comment: @GuitarFan, overflow: hidden; - обрежет весь контент, который будет "вылазить" (не поместится). Это бывает мешает. А clearfix просто будет очищать поток, но сохранять структуру. Да, громоздкий, но лучше использовать именно его.

Comment: Но ведь у content нет фиксированного размера, то есть он растягивается при заполнении, получается использование overflow: hidden; в этом случае позволительно? Или я что-то не учитываю еще?

Comment: Можете еще сказать, правильно ли я понимаю этот clearfix?
 content: "."; - вывести точку после формирования блока.
 display: block; - отображать точку (или то что вокруг нее?) как блок, не знаю зачем, возможно чтобы можно было использовать высоту.
 height: 0; - убрать высоту.
 clear: both; - Это наверное и есть самый важный стиль, чтобы убрать возможность обтекать элемент по бокам, то есть элемент с float выведется только после точки и без обтекания? 
 visibility: hidden; - не знаю зачем, у меня и без этого все уже было скрыто, так как высоту установили 0.

Comment: Почитайте о clearfix и о различных вариантах очищения потока.
http://css-live.ru/tricks/novaya-alternativa-clearfix-u-i-overflowhidden.html
http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/css-tricks/clearfix
http://webformyself.com/ochistka-plavayushhix-elementov-obzor-razlichnyx-metodov-clearfix/

Answer (score 3):

Потому что float не применяется к position: absolute;
правильнее будет написать так:

```
    #footer{
      float: left;
      background-color: #f4f6f9;
      border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 400;
      height: 60px;
      line-height: 60px;
    }
```