# Не удается закрепить footer

Tags: html, css, html5

Не получается закрепить footer.

Я пытался задать минимальную высоту странице вот так, чтобы footer выводился в конце:

CSS и HTML:

```css
html,
body {
  height: calc(100% - 90px)/* 90 - высота navbar и footer */
}

.bottom-bar {
  postion: absolute;
  bottom: 45px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <navbar></navbar>
  <div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-8 column">
        <!-- content -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 column">
        <!-- content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

В принципе, это работает, но есть одна ошибка - когда body растягивается, позиция footera не меняется. Как это исправить?

Вот так выводится footer сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот так должен выводится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "когда body растягивается"?

Comment: В него динамически добавляются элементы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: @ИльяБизунов у вас опечатка в ```css``` ```postion``` ===> ```position```

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы используете bootstrap, то `footer` добавить класс  `navbar-fixed-bottom`:

```js
if( $(document).height() <= $(window).height() ){  
  $(".bottom-bar").addClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<navbar>Navbar</navbar>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px">
  <div ng-view></div>

  Content
</div>

<div class="bottom-bar">
  bottom-bar
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8 column"> 
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 column">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

С контентом:

```js
if( $(document).height() <= $(window).height() ){  
  $(".bottom-bar").addClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <navbar>Navbar</navbar>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px; height: 1500px;">
        <div ng-view></div>
      
      Content
    </div>
  
    <div class="bottom-bar">
      bottom-bar
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-8 column"> 
                <!-- content -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 column">
                <!-- content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Кастомно:

```js
if( $(document).height() <= $(window).height() ){  
  $(".bottom-bar").addClass("fixed");
}
```

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<navbar>Navbar</navbar>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px">
  <div ng-view></div>

  Content
</div>

<div class="bottom-bar">
  bottom-bar
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8 column"> 
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 column">
      <!-- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет-нет, мне не нужен фиксированный футер. Попробую еще раз объяснить - если контент на странице занимает мала места по высоте - нужно вывести футер как на втором скрине. Если контента много - он должен быть в конце страницы.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов, поправила

Answer (score 0):

минимальная высота элементу задается через css-свойство min-height

Comment: С min-height не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего данную задачу решить при помощи флексбокса. Таким образом, высота футера может быть какой угодно и динамически меняться.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body class="page-body">
    <main role="main" class="page-content"></main>
    <footer class="page-footer"></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.page-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.page-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Да, я и флексбоксами пробовал - все арвно не получается. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Я прикрепил скриншоты в вопрос, может быть, посмотрев на них станет понятнее о чем я говорю.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось совсем просто. Я задал минимальную высоту не html и body, а контейнеру который в иерархии страницы находится выше, чем футер.

```
body > .container {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 177px);
}
```