# Прилипающий футер

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Мне нужно сделать прилипающий футер, у которого высота не фиксирована.
Сделал при помощи данного кода:

```
if ($(document).height() <= $(window).height()) {
        $("footer.footer").addClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");
    };
```

Но появилась проблема
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно что бы фоновая картинка была до конца страницы но если добавить в код блока с фоном `height: 100%;` то появляется вертикальная прокрутка, тк блок становится по высоте `body`. Как это можно исправить?
Расположение блоков

```
body
  header
  div class="full-width full-width-bg" //здесь фон
  footer class="footer "
```

Comment: А подвал получает position: fixed?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование для фиксированной высоты футера

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   content
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
```

#### 2. Решение через Flexbox для адаптивной высоты футера

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  /* Чтобы занимал оставшееся пространство */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

footer {
  /* Чтобы footer не уменьшался */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  content
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 3. Решение через таблицы для адаптивной высоты футера

```css
body {
  display: table;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: table-row;
  /* Чтобы ряд занимал всё оставшееся пространство, так как табличная разметка не позволит ему вытолкнуть header и footer */
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<main>
  content
</main>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

#### 4. Решение с использованием jQuery для адаптивной высоты футера

```js
// Высчитываем высоту footer и делаем соответствующий отступ от main:
function footer(){
$('main').css('padding-bottom',$('footer').height());
}
window.addEventListener('load',footer);
window.addEventListener('resize',footer);
```

```css
html {
  /* Растягиваем документ на всю высоту окна */
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  /* Растягиваем body по высоте html */
  min-height: 100%;
}

main {
   /* Выставляем отступ с высотой footer по умолчанию */
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

footer {
  /* Позиционируем footer внизу main */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Высота footer по умолчанию */
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
   header
  </header>
  <main>
   main
  </main>
  <footer>
   footer
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Второй вариант классный, только ie не хочет поддерживать.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  display: block;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 10vh;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 8 0;
}

footer {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1 0;
  min-height: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```