# Как сделать фон на всю высоту

Tags: css, вёрстка, веб-дизайн, блок

При уменьшении экрана, появляется вертикальная прокрутка, блок заполняется по высоте на 100% окна браузера, но при скроллинге блок поднимается вверх, тем самым закрывая внизу фоновое изображение. Как сделать чтобы фон был на всю высоту, даже при скроллинге?

[image: сайт на большом экране]

[image: сайт на планшетном разрешении и при скроллинге вниз]

Comment: Возможно, тебе поможет [css свойство **overflow**](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Приклеить footer к низу экрана на двухколоночном макете](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637285/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: не помогает:(..

Comment: Живой пример можно?

Comment: @Vadizar, успокойтесь. Приглашаем Вас в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/149852)

Comment: Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него код страницы, чтобы пользователи смогли дать лаконичный ответ. В противном случае, вопрос может быть закрыт проверяющими. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Yuri, всё указано же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а как оно поможет? Куда его указывать? Что там писать..

Comment: @Yuri, а чем оно по ссылке поможет? Получается, не та тревога... Впрочем, я что-то не пойму, поможет оно или нет.