# Разделить html страницу горизонтально со статическим размером нижней части

Tags: html, css

Не понимаю как разделить страницу на две части так, что бы нижняя имела фиксированную высоту и всегда находилась внизу экрана, не съезжая за край, а верхняя занимала все оставшееся пространство сверху.

В принципе, можно сделать, как в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-footer-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0), но в моем случае нужно иметь не только фиксированный подвал, но еще и динамическое масштабирование врехней части страницы, что бы она не оказалась под подвалом. Плюс не сразу понятно, что автор вопроса хочет получить.

Comment: Да по сути задача звучит просто, но мучаюсь уже не первый день. На странице есть два дива с графиками - один сверху, другой снизу, нижний имеет фиксированную высоту и не может ни растягиваться ни сжиматься, верхний же можно сжимать. Хочу сделать, что бы при открытии страницы на маленьком экране нижний график оставался таким, каким должно (и был при этом всегда на экране, что бы не приходилось прокручивать внизу), а верхний сжимался до определенных пределов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 5000px;
}

section {
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за height: calc(100vh - 70px);

Answer (score 2):

```css
.long{
  height: 3000px;
}
.d{
  height: 800px;
}
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}


* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "long">

Some content<br>
</div>
<div class = "d">
Some content
</div>
<div id = "footer">
footer

</div
```

Comment: что это ? `top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');` А главное зачем для такой элементарнейшей задачи?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Нижнюю часть зафиксировать получилось, а вот как в таком случае сделать динамическую высоту у верхней, что бы занималось все свободное пространство и не съезжало под нижнюю часть?
Ну и да, немного не понятно что делает предпоследняя строчка в css, попробовал без нее - вроде ничего не поменялось

Comment: -1 Это какая-то ересь с этим expression.

Comment: CSS expression было представлено в IE 5.0, зачем его использовать?

Answer (score 0):

```css
main {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(180, 180, 180, .4);
}

/* имитация длинной страницы */
main div {
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>Main content</div>
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```