# Чем заменить тег footer или как его ставить к низу сайта

Tags: html, css

Не получается никак его к низу прилепить, все перепробовал, а все равно контент уходит под него если задать ему стиль poeition: absolute; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%;
Как это исправить или чем его заменить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body class="Site">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main class="Site-content">Main</main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попpобую скажу. И еще один момент, если на сайте нету тега "main" то просто обернуть весь контент в тег "main"