# Занять div`ом всю оставшуюся высоту. Как?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Использую Bootstrtap 4. div-у с классом `h100percent` необходимо занять всю оставшуюся высоту в div-е `wrapper`. При этом `Header` фиксированной высоты располагается сверху, а `footer` фиксированной высоты снизу. Высота блока 100% т.е. разная от монитора к монитору.

P.S. В div .h100percent будет другой див размером больше него самого, т.е. должна быть полоса прокрутки overflow: auto. h100percent должен занять оставшееся место по высоте от футера и хэдера.
P.P.S "Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?" не решает моей проблемы, там блок контента не занимает все оставшуюся высоту.

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.h100percent {
  /* Занять все оставшееся место */
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <title>Help me!</title>
</head>

<body style='background-color: #BDBDBD'>

  <div class="wrapper" style='background-color: BROWN; '>
    <div class="container" style='background-color: ORANGE'>
      <div class="row" style='background-color: GREEN'>

        <div class="col-12" style='background-color: BLUE'>Header</div>

        <div class="col-12 h100percent" style='background-color: GoldenRod'>Этот блок должен занять всю оставшуюся высоту</div>

        <div class="col-12" style='background-color: CORAL'>Foter</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 8):

Для такой задачи подходит `flex-box`. Нужно разместить блоки в контейнере `flex` 100%-высоты, а в блок, который нужно растянуть, добавить правило  `flex-grow`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.header {
  background: green
}

.h100 {
  background: yellow;
  flex-grow: 3
}

.footer {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class=flex>
  <div class=header>Верхний блок</div>
  <div class=h100>Контент</div>
  <div class=footer>Нижний блок</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если `header` и `footer` фиксированной высоты, допустим по `70px`, можно сделать так:

```
.h100percent {
  height: calc(100vh - 140px);
}
```

Тогда ваш `.h100percent` получит высоту, равную высоте окна браузера и вычтет высоту хедер+футер

Comment: А поддержка calc(100vh - 140px); как? Желательно что бы в большинстве мобильных браузеров тоже это работало.

Comment: Работает, смотрите тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc в разделе поддержки браузерами