# Вылазит текст за поле

Tags: html, css

Вылазит длинный текст....

[image: Изображение]

Пробовал `white-space: normal`, но тогда строка начинается с абзаца, а мне нужно чтобы текст был вряд и не вылазил...

Сам код:

```html
<select size="1" autocomplete="shipping country" data-backup="country" class="field__input field__input--select" aria-required="true" name="order_delivery_method" id="checkout_shipping_address_country">
  <option>Новая Почта (Оплата при получении 1233333333333)</option>
  <option>Новая Почта (Полная предоплата)</option>
  <option>Новая Почта (Частичная предоплата)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Вообще ничего не понять. Кода нет, данных нет, текст не вмещается в блок или  в `input` таблицы стилей заданы или нет. Если родитель ограничен по ширине то текст длиннее родителя не войдет.

Comment: @Alex добавил код!

Comment: @RuslanSemenov добавил код!

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин в добавленном коде проблема не наблюдается. добавьте больше информации, чтобы воспроизвести Вашу проблему. предполагаем, что Вы используете плагин.

Comment: Спасибо, но что именно нужно? У меня все поместилось. Какие стили?

Comment: @Alex собственно вот сайт: http://185.185.69.207/cart2.php?action=confirm, и там как видно текст вылазит...

Comment: @RuslanSemenov собственно вот сайт: http://185.185.69.207/cart2.php?action=confirm, и там как видно текст вылазит...

Comment: Не стоит дублировать для нас ответы. А так, сократите `option` в две строки он не формируется, или измените на `group`

Comment: @RuslanSemenov спасибо, но можно, пожалуйста, подробнее? Если Вы имеете ввиду сократить сам текст с переносом на новую строку то не получится ибо текст берется из бд.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин Вам так нужно сделать http://prntscr.com/hflo56 ?

Comment: @Alex дааа, именно так, только если можно чуть-чуть левее.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин что значит чуть-чуть левее ? больше обрезать текст справа?

Comment: Возможно я не понял, что нужно, я так понял, что длинный текст невозможно прочитать, а не вместить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте правило:

```
.floating-labels .field--show-floating-label .field__input{
   padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Comment: это нужно найти класс .floating-labels .field--show-floating-label .field__input{ и добавить туда паддинг или же создать класс?

Comment: либо найти это правило и добавить в него либо в конец файла стилей добавить данное правило

Comment: посмотрите как на телефонном экране вылазит option, разве так и должно быть? http://webmark.com.ua/mobile/?url=http%3A%2F%2F185.185.69.207%2Fcart2.php%3Faction%3Dconfirm

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин вы с телефона посмотрите

Comment: с телефона нет возможности, по этому приходится использовать сервис webmark

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин при просмотре с телефона наверняка  Вас не вылезет текст справа от телефона :) а если серьезно, на телефоне  своя стилизация селекта и весь текст виден и помещается.

Comment: насмешили :) спасибо вам большое, пожалуйста, подскажите ещё как убрать этот отступ? чтобы я не создавал новый топик да и мне нелья http://prntscr.com/hflxcl

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин это не отступ, это пустое пространство. [прижмите футер к низу страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/546490/191745).

Answer (score 1):

Вот как пример, использования вместо `select option`

```css
body {
  background: skyblue;
}

div {
  background: white;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="val1"> Очень длинный текст с описанием, и всем, что вашей деше угодно. Лорем тут жалко не поддерживается :)<br>
  <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="val2"> Второй<br>
  <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="val3"> Третий<br>

</div>
```

Comment: где же вы там `radio` увидели?

Comment: Его там нет, я предлагаю выход, при длинных текстах использование `radio` вместо длинного `option`

Comment: видимо вы не поняли, что хотел автор

Comment: Да, я об этом и сказал, поэтому подтвердил ваше решение.