# Как блок поиска по категории прижать к footer'у?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background: white;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Segoe wp light", sans-serif;
}

#browse {
  color: #7e7e7e;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table {
  color: #b9b9b9;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.category {
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  background-color: #484242;
  color: #959292;
  height: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

p.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>LEO IMAGES</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="banner">

      </div>

      <div class="category">
        <h1 id="browse">BROWSE BY CATEGORY</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Abstract</td>
            <td>Business/Finance</td>
            <td>Holidays</td>
            <td>Nature</td>
            <td>Signs/Symbols</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Animals/Wildlife</td>
            <td>Celebrities</td>
            <td>Illustrations/Clip-Art</td>
            <td>Objects</td>
            <td>Sports/Recreation</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>The Arts</td>
            <td>Editorial</td>
            <td>Industrial</td>
            <td>Parks/Outdoor</td>
            <td>Technology</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bacgrounds/Textures</td>
            <td>Education</td>
            <td>Interiors</td>
            <td>People</td>
            <td>Transportation</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Beauty/Fashion</td>
            <td>Food and Drink</td>
            <td>Miscellaneous</td>
            <td>Religion</td>
            <td>Vectors</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Buildings/Landmarks</td>
            <td>Healthcare/Medical</td>
            <td>Model Released Only</td>
            <td>Science</td>
            <td>Vintage</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p class="footer">Copyrigth &copy 2013 Css Author</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обернуть их в один див

Comment: Добавьте ваш [mcve], без кода можно только гадать, что там и как у вас, одно и то же можно верстать разными способами

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: Не думаю. У меня блок footer уже прижат.

Comment: Извиняюсь за плохой скриншот.

Comment: Может вы перестанете задавать один и тот же вопрос?

Comment: Я ответ не получил.

Comment: а, ну тогда продолжайте ...

Answer (score 0):

Работа с flex, который задаётся для body. Позиционирование удаляем. Задача решается.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: "Segoe wp light", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#browse {
  color: #7e7e7e;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table {
  color: #b9b9b9;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.category {
  width: 100%;
  }

footer {
  background-color: #484242;
  color: #959292;
  height: 44px;
  width: 100%;

}

p.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="banner">

      </div>

      <div class="category">
        <h1 id="browse">BROWSE BY CATEGORY</h1>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Abstract</td>
            <td>Business/Finance</td>
            <td>Holidays</td>
            <td>Nature</td>
            <td>Signs/Symbols</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Animals/Wildlife</td>
            <td>Celebrities</td>
            <td>Illustrations/Clip-Art</td>
            <td>Objects</td>
            <td>Sports/Recreation</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>The Arts</td>
            <td>Editorial</td>
            <td>Industrial</td>
            <td>Parks/Outdoor</td>
            <td>Technology</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bacgrounds/Textures</td>
            <td>Education</td>
            <td>Interiors</td>
            <td>People</td>
            <td>Transportation</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Beauty/Fashion</td>
            <td>Food and Drink</td>
            <td>Miscellaneous</td>
            <td>Religion</td>
            <td>Vectors</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Buildings/Landmarks</td>
            <td>Healthcare/Medical</td>
            <td>Model Released Only</td>
            <td>Science</td>
            <td>Vintage</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p class="footer">Copyrigth &copy 2013 Css Author</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```