# Найти фактор недающий прижать футер(подвал) к низу страницы

Tags: html, css

Это не дубликат "как сделать правильно футер" и тд.

Ситуация следующая: подвал прижимается правильно только когда страница отдалена на 50%
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если страницу приблизить до 100% так как должно быть, появляется правый скролл и подвал отделяется от низа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML Код страницы:

```
[noajax]
<header>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="{description}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{keywords}">
    <title>Sampwar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sampwar.ru/css/monbutton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/simpleTooltip.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/toastr.min.css">
    <link href="/css/font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/wysibb/theme/default/wbbtheme.css" />
    <link href="/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script  src = "/js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.circliful.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.pwstabs-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/wysibb/jquery.wysibb.js"></script>
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/highstock.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/users.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/slider.js"></script>    
    [login]<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var user_info = [];
    user_info['id'] = {accountsid};
    </script>[/login]
</header>
      <body>
 <div style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto;">
    <div id='navigation_title2'>
      {header}
      <div class="page-content">
          <div class="index">
       <div class="content-index" id="content-base">{content} </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>              

<div id="footer"></div> 

<div id="modal"></div>
[/noajax]
</body>
</html>

[ajax]
{content}
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="nurl_title">{title}</div>
</div>
[/ajax]
```

CSS Код:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
   background: url(https://forum.sampwar.ru/styles/brivium/silver/extra/bg-body.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}


.page-content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}

#footer {
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
}
```

Ссылка на сайт: https://sampwar.ru

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

замените в body height: 100% на min-height: 100%

и также добавьте body position: relative

Должно решить проблему.