# Перемещение элемента вниз

Tags: html, css

Как перенести элемент вниз[image: Код]? Есть два слова "Смотреть работу" и они находятся не на одном уровне и я хочу переместить их на один уровень. Как это сделать?

[image: То, что нужно перенести]

Comment: [Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-footer-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов можно так:

```css
.block {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
.bottom {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
        -ms-flex-align: end;
            align-items: flex-end;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.div{
    width:300px; 
    padding: 10px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
        -ms-flex-align: stretch;
            align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
        align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-item-align: stretch;
        align-self: stretch;
}

/**************TWO*****************/
 html, body{
    height: 100%;
 }

.two p {
    height: 100%;
}
.block_two {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
.two {
    width: 212px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
<div class="div">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.  </p>
<a href="#!" class="bottom">Смотреть работы</a>
</div> 
<div class="div">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
<a href="#!" class="bottom">Смотреть работы</a>
</div> 
</div>


<h3>Вариант 2:</h3>
<div class="block_two">
<div class="two">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
<a href="#!">Смотреть</a>
</div>

<div class="two">
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
<a href="#!">Смотреть</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня "смотреть работы" - это как ссылка :) Мне ссылку заворачивать в div?

Comment: @Ярослав вы серьезно это спрашиваете?

Comment: @Ярослав Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, ибо я уже час борюсь с этим вопросом :) Я новичок) Меня понять можно. Я никогда не видел ссылку в диве(

Comment: @Ярослав вариантов много как это можно сделать

Comment: Вот именно, что уже все перепробовал и ничего) Твой код даже попробовал. Если бы не был перфекционистом вообще плевать было бы на эти "Смотреть работы"

Comment: В примере же работает, значит вы что то не так делаете :) Можно сделать это с помощью  JS/Jquery

Comment: Даниил, спасибо тебе большое!!!! Второй способ очень помог. Очень большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Ярослав будь добр и отметь данный ответ как верный)