# Не получается прижать футер. Появляется полоса прокрутки

Tags: html, css

Ломаю голову и никак не пойму в чем проблема.

Надо прижать `footer` к низу страницы. Для этого использовал способ с `flex-box`. При этом появляется полоса прокрутки. Если добавить свойство `overflow: hidden`, `footer` вовсе исчезает. Если вместо `height: 100%` использовать `min-height: 100%`, `footer` не прижимается к низу.

Структура страницы:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.wraper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.contacts_footer {
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

.copyrights {
  float: right;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header_top">
      <div class="contacts">
        <p>
          +380966579797
          <br> shock@gmail.com
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="login">
        <a href="login"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="registration">
        <a href="reg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header_middle">
      <div class="header_logo">

      </div>
      <div class="header_search">

      </div>
      <div class="header_basket">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header_bottom">
      <div class="top_menu">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wraper">

</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="contacts_footer">
    +380966579797
    <br> shock@gmail.com
  </div>
  <div class="copyrights">
    ©Comp 2018
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавил `background-color` для наглядности

Comment: Если честно, не совсем понятно, чего ты именно хочешь добиться...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все верно у тебя wraper занимает 100% экрана + footer занимает 100px
2 варианта выполнения

1) через calc - это функция CSS, которая даёт возможность рассчитать значения свойств CSS во время их определения

https://jsfiddle.net/eyhcv9ok/1/

```
.header{
    height: 100px;
}
.wraper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

1) через позиционирование flex

https://jsfiddle.net/ybh6tav0/2/

```
body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}

.wraper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.footer{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Извините что поздно отвечаю, только сейчас вернулся к работе. Первый вариант не очень хороший в том случае если высота footer может изменится. А второй вроде нормально работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    height: 100%;
     display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.wraper{
    width:100%;
}
```