# Не могу прижать футер к низу при высоком разрешении экрана

Tags: html, css, wordpress, вёрстка, bootstrap

Проблема в том, что футер отображается не всегда внизу страницы (зависит от того, с какого разрешения экрана смотреть страницу). На отдельных страницах сайта мало контента и футер липнет к блоку с контентом. Пробовал играть с позиционированием и высотой блока с контентом - не помогло. Может, я что не так делаю, подскажите)

Сайт имеет такую структуру:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="outer_dpage"></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="outer-footer"></div>
</body>
```

Помогите! Всю голову сломал уже, почему он не всегда внизу)

Comment: `.outer-footer{position:fixed;height:50px;bottom:0} .outer_dpage{margin-bottom: 50px;}`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос, по большому счёту, к WordPress отношения не имеет - это чистая вёрстка. Добавьте в style.css вашей темы

```
.outer-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы футер был прижат и на длинных и на коротких страницах, то задайте жёстко высоту header, высоту footer и вычисляйте высоту контента:

```
header {
    height: 100px;
}
.outer_dpage {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 100px - 50px);
}
.outer-footer {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: так работает) но он теперь всегда отображается на странице (на главной контента много и до футера надо еще пролистать), а с фиксированной позицией он немного мешает просмотру. на остальных страницах (где мало контента) все круто! Может можно как-то заставить другие блоки быть высотой 100% и тогда футер будет всегда внизу относительно них?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо огромное!!

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.