# Как можно исправить footer?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]После того как я прижал footer,  возникла проблема -

рейтинг фильмов зашёл на footer и теперь не видно его. Помогите пожалуйста .

html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Фильмы онлайн в HD</title>
    <meta name="discription" content="Кипомонстр - это портал о кино">
    <meta name="keywords" content="фильмы, фильмы онлайн, hd">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main"> 

     <div class="header"> 

         <div class="logo">

             <div class="logo_text"> 
                <h1><a href="/">КиноМонстр</a></h1>
                <h2>Кино - наша страсть!</h2>
              </div>
         </div>
        <div class="menubar">

        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>

        </div>

     </div>

          <div class="site_content">
           <div class="sidebar_container">
             <div class="sidebar">
                <h2>Поиск</h2>
                <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
                     <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос"/>
                     <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти"/>
                </form>

             </div>
              <div class="sidebar">
                  <h2>Вход</h2>

                  <form method="post" action="#" id="login"> 

                  <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
                 <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
                 <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
              <div class="lables_passreg_text">
                <span><a href="#">забыли пароль?</a></span> <br> <span><a href="#">регистрация</a></span>   

              </div>

                  </form>

          </div>
          <div class="sidebar">
            <h2>Новости</h2>
          <span>31.02.2019</span>
          <p>Мы запустили расширенный поиск фильмов на сайте</p>
          <a href="#">ЧИТАТЬ</a>


          </div>

       <div class="sidebar">
         <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Интерстеллар</a><span class="rating_sidebar">8.1</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Матрица</a><span class="rating_sidebar">5.3</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Безумный Макс</a><span class="rating_sidebar">6.8</span></li>
              <li><a href="#">Облачный атлас</a><span class="rating_sidebar">4.3</span></li>
            </ul>

       </div>

      </div>

      <div class="footer">
          <p>

            <a href="#">Главная</a>
            <a href="#">Фильмы</a>
            <a href="#">Сериалы</a>
            <a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a>
            <a href="#">Контакты</a>
          </p>
          <p>wh-db.com 2015</p>

      </div> 

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

css -

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
font-size: 1em;
background-color: #fff;
color: #555;
}

p {
font:normal 100% 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
padding: 0 0 13px 0;
line-height: 1.4em;
}

input [type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="search"] {
color : #5d5d5d;
width: 60%;
padding: 0px;
}

input, textarea {
outline: none;
border: none;
border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1, h2 {
font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
margin: 0 0 15px 0;
padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
color: #000;
}

h2 {
font-size: 140%;
}

a, a:hover {
font: normal 90% 'Tahoma bold', sans-serif;
outline: none;
text-decoration: underline;
color: #aeb002;
}

ul {
margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
font: normal 100% 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
margin: 0 0 6px 0;
padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
line-height: 1.2em;
}

.header  {
background-color:  darkslateblue;
height: 177px;
font-size: 0.8em;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
min-width: 900px;
}

.main, .logo, .menubar, .site_content, .footer {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
width: 880px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1, .logo h2 {
font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1, .logo_text h1 a, .logo_text h1 a:hover {
padding-top: 22px 0 0 0;
color: #fff;
letter-spacing:  0.1em;
text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
font-size: 1.2em;
padding: 4px 0 0 0;
color: #999;
}

.menubar {
width: 780px;
height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
float: left;
padding: 0 0 0 9px;
list-style: none;
margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
font: normal 100% 'trebushet ms', sans-serif;
display: block;
height: 20px;
padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
width: 880px;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_container {
float:right;
width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
float:right;
width: 222px;
padding: 5%;
margin: 0 0 16px 0;
border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
padding: 8px;
background-color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
color: #136cd2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
font: normal 100% 'Tahoma bold', sans-serif;
font-size: 0.8em;
margin-top: 2%;
margin-left: 0%;
}

.sidebar ul {
margin: 0;
}

.sidebar ul li {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar .rating_sidebar {
float: right;
}

.footer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
padding: 28px 0 5px 0;
text-align: center;
background-color: darkslateblue;
color: #a8aa94;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
min-width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: для начала прочитай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/Как-всегда-прижимать-footer-к-низу-экрана 
Хотя бы 1ый вариант . Решение через абсолютное позиционирование для фиксированной высоты футера

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, в вашей разметке не хватает закрывающего div перед body.

Во вторых на 84 строке в стилях `padding-top: 22px 0 0 0;`. Обратите внимание `padding-top` не может иметь четыре параметра.

В третьих, попробуйте положить ваш `<footer/>` на уровень выше в `<div class='main'/>` и уберите в `<footer/>` стили `position: absolute;`.

По идее должно всё работать.

P.S. Сейчас подумал, если нужно, чтобы footer всегда был виден, а скролился только контент, то тогда можно поставить `position: sticky;` на `<footer/>`. Надеюсь что-то из этого поможет.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  font: normal 100% 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 0 13px 0;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

input [type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 0px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%;
}

a,
a:hover {
  font: normal 90% 'Tahoma bold', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
  font: normal 100% 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.main,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding-top: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999;
}

.menubar {
  width: 780px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebushet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
  width: 880px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_container {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 222px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cd2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font: normal 100% 'Tahoma bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.sidebar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 28px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  color: #a8aa94;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Фильмы онлайн в HD</title>
  <meta name="discription" content="Кипомонстр - это портал о кино">
  <meta name="keywords" content="фильмы, фильмы онлайн, hd">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">

    <div class="header">

      <div class="logo">

        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">КиноМонстр</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - наша страсть!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menubar">

        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="site_content">
      <div class="sidebar_container">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Поиск</h2>
          <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
            <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти" />
          </form>

        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Вход</h2>

          <form method="post" action="#" id="login">

            <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
            <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
            <div class="lables_passreg_text">
              <span><a href="#">забыли пароль?</a></span> <br> <span><a href="#">регистрация</a></span>

            </div>

          </form>

        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Новости</h2>
          <span>31.02.2019</span>
          <p>Мы запустили расширенный поиск фильмов на сайте</p>
          <a href="#">ЧИТАТЬ</a>


        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">
          <h2>Рейтинг фильмов</h2>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Интерстеллар</a><span class="rating_sidebar">8.1</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Матрица</a><span class="rating_sidebar">5.3</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Безумный Макс</a><span class="rating_sidebar">6.8</span></li>
            <li><a href="#">Облачный атлас</a><span class="rating_sidebar">4.3</span></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>

        <a href="#">Главная</a>
        <a href="#">Фильмы</a>
        <a href="#">Сериалы</a>
        <a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a>
        <a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </p>
      <p>wh-db.com 2015</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Отличный, полезный ответ. Не понятно, почему люди проходят мимо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте после рейтинга фильмов вставить ещё один пустой div высотой с футер который будет выполнять только вспомогательную роль:

`<div class='rating_sidebar-helper'></div>`

Ну и CSS:

`.rating_sidebar-helper {
    height: 50px; /* Ну или сколько там у Вас */ 
}`