# Не получается прижать футер к низу экрана

Tags: html, css, адаптивность

Не поможете с футером? Он "отклеивается", может быть, дело в том , что данный код некроссбраузерный?

```css
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer span {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer"><span>текст футера</span></div>
```

Comment: Не очень плонял, кто откуда отклеивается?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вам его прижать вниз надо?

```
#footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:50px;
background: #000;
text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: для @Denis ;  position: absolute; - не чревато? при адаптивной верстке, например, для ios, футер оказывается над перекрывающим высоту тела сайта контентом?

Comment: Ну тогда флексом, как в ответе рядом

Comment: ну да, можно попробовать

Answer (score 0):

Можно флексом.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header, section, footer {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.wrapper > section {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>header</header>
  <section>section</section>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```