# Как переместить Футер вниз страницы?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
iput[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 170% 'century gothic', arial;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%;
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.header {
  background-color: darkslateblue;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.main,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'centure gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo_text h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999;
}

.menubar {
  width: 900px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
  width: 880px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.sidebar_container {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 222px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.sidebar ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Главная страница</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Киномостр - это портал о кино" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="фильмы,фильмы онлайн, hd" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="main">

    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="logo_text">
          <h1><a href="/">КиноМонстр</a></h1>
          <h2>Кино - наша страсть!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menubar">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Фильмы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="site_content">
    <div class="sidebar_container">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Поиск</h2>
        <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form">
          <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="ваш запрос" />
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="найти" />
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Вход</h2>
        <form method="post" action="#" id="login">

          <input type="text" name="login_field" placeholder="логин" />
          <input type="password" name="password_field" placeholder="пароль" />
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="вход" />
          <div class="lables_passreg_text">
            <span><a href="#">забыли пароль?</a></span> |
            <span><a href="#">рагистрация</a></span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Новости</h2>
        <span>21.04.2020</span>
        <p>Мы запустили расширенный поиск</p>
        <a href="#">читать</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>Рейтинг фильмов </h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Интерстелар</a><span class="rating_sidebar">8.1</span></li>
          <li><a href="#">Матрица</a><span class="rating_sidebar">8.0</span></li>
          <li><a href="#">Безумный Макс</a><span class="rating_sidebar">7.5</span></li>
          <li><a href="#">Облачный атлас</a><span class="rating_sidebar">7.4</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        <a href="#">Главная</a> |
        <a href="#">Фильмы</a> |
        <a href="#">Сериалы</a> |
        <a href="#">Рейтинг фильмов</a> |
        <a href="#">Контакты</a> |

      </p>
      <p>wh-db.com 2015</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: футер должен быть за пределами класса site_content, или в пределах данного класса?

Comment: Ответ Gayrat Vlasov правильный : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/eYpBPJP

Answer (score 0):

Отличная статья по Вашему вопросу написана здесь:
https://learn.javascript.ru/float

Лучшим решением в Вашем случае мне думается будет написать перед footer еще один div:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="footer">
```

Конечно работает и просто добавление clear: both в класс footer, но при этом если Вам захочется поставить margin-top: 200px у footer - то это не будет работать (см. статью)

Comment: Спасибо огромное!