# Как сделать так, чтобы footer был в конце страницы?

Tags: php, html, css

Товарищи, помогите пожалуйста. Как сделать так, чтобы footer был в конце страницы вне зависимости от величины контента?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-image: url("images/carouselback.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 70%;
    background-position-y: 65%;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    height: 120px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: linear-gradient(transparent, #30ff00);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(transparent, #00c6ff);
}
body {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
/* Шапка и логин */
.headmain {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: gold;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: oblique;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.headmain a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: lawngreen;
}
.headmain a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: lawngreen;
}

/*Верхнее меню*/
.topmenu li { display: inline; }
.topmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
    border: 1px solid #c2c6c8;
    font-family: Consolas;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px grey;
}
.topmenu_kid {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
    font-family: Consolas;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10%;
}
.topmenu_kid_right {
    margin: 0 0 0 80%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.topmenu a {
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.topmenu a:hover {
    color: red;
}
/*Основное меню с товаром и скидками*/
.linemenu li { display: inline; }
.linemenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: black;
    font-family: Consolas;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 0;
}
.linemenu a {
    position: relative;
    color: #2196f3;
    padding: 20px 35px;
    font-size: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.linemenu a:hover {
    color: #255784;
    background:  #2196f3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2196f3, 0 0 40px #2196f3, 0 0 80px #2196f3;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
a span  {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
a span:nth-child(1) {
    top:0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}
a:hover span:nth-child(1){
    left: 100%;
    transition: 0.7s;
}
a span:nth-child(3) {
    bottom:0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}
a:hover span:nth-child(3){
    right: 100%;
    transition: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
a span:nth-child(2) {
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}
a:hover span:nth-child(2){
    top: 100%;
    transition: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
a span:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #2196f3);
}
a:hover span:nth-child(4){
    bottom: -00%;
    transition: 0.7s;
    transition-delay: 0.75s;
}

/*Регистрация*/
#reg {
    margin: 10% 40%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ECEDF0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 40%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 150;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2196f3, 0 0 40px #2196f3, 0 0 80px #2196f3;
}
#reg input[type=text] {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    color: brown;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px white;
}
#reg input[type=password] {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    color: brown;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px white;
}
#reg input[type=submit] {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px black;
}
#regmistake {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    border: 1px solid orangered;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
}
.close {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 20px 20px 10px 87%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close:hover {
    background: grey;
}

/*Вход на сайт*/
#auth {
    margin: 10% 40%;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ECEDF0;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 150;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #2196f3, 0 0 40px #2196f3, 0 0 80px #2196f3;
}
#auth input[type=text] {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    color: brown;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px white;
}
#auth input[type=password] {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    color: brown;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    margin: 4px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px white;
}
#auth input[type=submit] {
    width: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    padding: 4px 2px;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px black;
}
#authmistake {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
    border: 1px solid orangered;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
}
/*Затемнение*/
#gray {
    background-color: rgba(1,1,1,0.75);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
/*Карусель*/
.slideshow-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1300px;
    top: 30%;
    left: 18%;
}
.mySlides {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 500px;
}
.mySlides img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
.prev, .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -40px;
    color: #ECEDF0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 60px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.prev {
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
    color: #00c6ff;
}
/*Футер*/

footer {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    height : 30%;
    bottom : 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ECEDF0;
    background-color: #272727;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
```

```html
<head>
    <?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/head.php';
    ?>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Задний прозрачный фон -->
<div onclick="go('none')" id = "gray"></div>
<div onclick="show('none')" id = "gray"></div>
    <?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
    ?>
<div class="carouselback"></div>
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/carousel.php';
?>
    <?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/main.php';
    ?>
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/getin.php';
?>
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/reg.php';
?>
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/carousel.js';
?>
</body>
<footer>
    <?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/footer.php';
    ?>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как всегда прижимать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте такой вариант вёрстки.
При ней футер будет всегда снизу.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  background: #ddd;
}

.footer {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```