# Сделать footer и закрепить его в низу страницы?

Tags: html, css, scss

необходимо сделать footer и закрепить его в низу страницы

```
    <div class="footer">
      <h1>Belzer<br>Design</h1>
      <div class="footer-contacts">
        <a href=""><img src="/img/mail.svg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="/img/instagram.svg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="/img/vk.svg" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="/img/behance.svg" alt=""></a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.footer {
    margin-top: 110px;
    background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.footer h1 {
    margin-left: 166px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и чего? зы: h1 в футер вряд ли стоит пихать

Comment: Прошу прощения, я просто новичок.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прижать footer к низу экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546490/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-footer-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: Это всё хорошо, только вот я не могу разместить логотипы соц.сетей на футере, они у меня вылезают из него. И почему-то показывается, что логотип занимает всю ширину футера.

Comment: Я правильно понял, у Вас не получается расставить ```h1``` и ```.footer-contacts``` по разным сторонам ```.footer```?

Comment: Да, Вы правильно поняли.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй задать position: fixed;

```
selector {
  position: fixed;
}
```